# python - how to downgrade openssl

Tags: python, ssl

Im having issues with some older certs that are self generated by my routers. I believe it is because openssl no longer supports 3des encryption.

I would like to downgrade my ssl version in python to see if the problems go away.

Current Version:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016'
>>>
```

I am using the docker image for python. and that runs:

```
# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l
```

Im not sure which version 3des was removed in, but I would need to use the version before that I think.

I'm using aiohttp which I believe uses urllib3 for requests and I haven't been able to get past the handshake failure currently, which I believe is because of 3des encryption?

Comment: You did not even name your OS and its version.

Comment: @KlausD. I've added the OS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out the version of OpenSSL you want. Taking the example of version 1.0.0, use the following command:

```
sudo pip install 'pyOpenSSL==21.0.0' --force-reinstall
```

Full list of old pyOpenSSL released versions: https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/

Comment: I tried with 0.9.6 and 1.0.0 and got an error# pip install 'openssl==0.9.6' --force-reinstall
Collecting openssl==0.9.6
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openssl==0.9.6 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openssl==0.9.6
# pip install 'openssl==1.0.0' --force-reinstall
Collecting openssl==1.0.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openssl==1.0.0 (from versions: )
No matc

Comment: You have to check pypi to find a valid version that can be collected.

Comment: how do I use pypi?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL

Check the previous versions and find the one you want to try, use that specific version number to get it.